# Is $\mathbb N$ dense in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: general-topology

Is $\mathbb N$ dense in $\mathbb R$?

Let say $(a,b)=(0,1)$ How come it does not contain an element of $\mathbb N$?

Is it because it's an open interval?

Can someone please explain this to me? Also when would it be dense?

Comment: Depends on your topology.

Comment: @voldemort Do you think such pedantry is helpful? It also depends on what you mean by $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, the said interval doesn't contain a natural number because it is an open interval with its endpoints themselves being two consequtive natural numbers.

Comment: In short, you've just proved that $\mathbb N$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$

Comment: Depending on the convention, $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of all non-negative integers, or the set of positive integers. The set $(0, 1)$ is the set of all real numbers between $0$ and $1$ but not including $0$ or $1$; this set contains no integers, in particular, no elements of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Being an open interval alone does not mean it doesn't contain a natural number. $(0,2)$ contains a natural number.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I think the last part asks- when will it be dense in $\mathbb{R}$- that answer depends on the topology.

Comment: You are humorous! Please refer to the definitions of $\mathbb{N}$ and being dense.

Comment: @Brian: Put the trivial, or indiscrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$. (Sarcasm without facts loses its sting).

Comment: @Brian Please point me where in the definition you saw the answer .tks

Comment: @voldemort: Well, take easy, I meant no disrespect. I call unusual propositions humorous (note that it is unusual rather than trivial). It has nothing to do with sarcasm :)

Answer (score 5):

$$\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,4,5,\ldots\}.$$

In order that $\mathbb N$ be dense in $\mathbb R$ it would be necessary for every open interval about every member of $\mathbb R$ to contain a member of $\mathbb N$.  Even if $(0,1)$ did contain a member of $\mathbb N$ (and it does not) there would still be open intervals about $0.5$ containing no member of $\mathbb N$, for example $(0.4,0.6)$.  The existence of at least one open interval containing $0.5$ and not intersecting $\mathbb N$ means $0.5$ is not a limit point of $\mathbb N$.  Only if every point in $\mathbb R$ were a limit point of $\mathbb N$ would $\mathbb N$ be dense in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume you are using the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{R}_{std}$ as I was taught). A subset of $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is dense if $\bar A = \mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{\bar N} \neq \mathbb{R}$. So no, $\mathbb{N}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R.}$ If you need to prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is closed under $\mathbb{R}_{std}$, it suffices to observe that $$\bigcup _{i=1}^\infty (i,i+1) \cup(-\infty,1)$$ is open, and $$\left(\bigcup _{i=0}^\infty (i,i+1) \cup(-\infty,0) \right)^{c}=\mathbb{N}$$ is therefore closed.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. That was the notation I learned in class, but it didn't occur to me that it was not common.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to tell apart the standard notation (pun not intended) from a particular lecture(rer)'s idiosyncrasies. Worse yet when there's no standard notation at all. On the other hand, I believe in spelling things out as opposed to using a lot of symbols (taking practical considerations into account, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Every other answer tells you that in the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{N}$ is not dense.

So, to get $\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, you have to change the topology. Notice that $\mathbb{N}$ is indeed dense in $\mathbb{R}$ in the indiscrete topology (every non empty set is open in the indiscrete topology.)

Answer (score 2):

Show that a subspace $\;D\;$ of a topological space $\;X\;$ is dense in it iff $\;D\cap Y\neq\emptyset\;$ for all open non-empty $\;Y\subset X\;$ .

Then, and under the usual topology of $\;\Bbb R\;$, your example shows $\;\Bbb N\;$ isn't dense here since $\;(0,1)\cap\Bbb N=\emptyset\;$

Answer (score 1):

The interval $(0,1)$ does not contain a natural number.

The fact doesn't follow from the fact that it is an open interval (after all, $(0,2)$ is also an open interval, and it contains $1$, which is a natural number).

Of course, there are natural numbers in the closed interval $[0,1]$ (namely $0$ and $1$, or just $1$ if you don't consider $0$ to be a natural number), but that has nothing to do with the closedness: the interval $[\frac{1}{3},\frac 2 3 ]$ is also closed, but doesn't contain any natural numbers.

However, it can be easily seen from the fact that $(0,1)$ is, by the definition, the set of real numbers strictly larger than $0$ and strictly smaller than $1$. But there are no natural numbers with that property, so there are no natural numbers in $(0,1)$.

Because $(0,1)$ is an open set, it intersects any dense subset of ${\bf R}$. This implies that ${\bf N}$ is not dense in ${\bf R}$, as it does not intersect $(0,1)$.